# Control the sliding speed of the drawer in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I've seen an app (Xyanyu) with a smoother navigation. I am not sure if they were using a drawer widget, but it was sliding slower. Is there any way to control the sliding speed of the drawer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inner_drawer#-readme-tab-) package flutter_innner_drawer can do the trick, you can set the animation duration and even customize the animation of the drawer